# Giphy API always gives the same gifs (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, giphy, giphy-api

This might be innapropriate, but I am making a discord bot, and in the process I wanted to make a "gif" command. I had chosen the Giphy api as it seemed to be the most simple one out there. But everytime I ask the bot to fetch a trending gif, it gives me the same gifs. (Example attached)
[Here you can see he bot sending the same gif 2 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ9tM.png)

Here is the code needed for this command:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gif`)) {
    giphy.trending('gifs', {limit:100})
        .then((response) => {
            var totalResponses = response.data.length;
            var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % totalResponses;
            var responseFinal = response.data[responseIndex];
               
            message.channel.send("Here is a gif for you!\n", {
                files: [responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url]
            }).catch(() => {
                message.channel.send('There was an API error, please try later.')
            })
        })
}
```

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never worked with the giphy API, but you are just trying to get a random index from an array and that is simply done by doing:

```js
var totalResponses = response.data.length;
var responseIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalResponses);
var responseFinal = response.data[responseIndex];

message.channel.send("Here is a gif for you!\n", {
                   files: [responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url]
               }).catch(() => {
                   message.channel.send('There was an API error, please try later.')
               })
```

`totalResponses` is the length of the array, which we need to get a random number from. That is done in `responseIndex`. So now in `responseIndex` a random number from 0 to `totalResponses` is stored (and that is exactly what we wanted, because an array always starts at 0, so 0 could be a possible index). Then in `responseFinal`, we store the value of the array at the random index from `responseIndex`.